# Difference between .. and ... in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between .. and ... in a ruby for loop.

```
for num in 1..5
    puts num
end
```

vs

```
for num in 1...5
    puts num
end
```

How are those two loops different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby `1...5` gives you a range which doesn't include `5`
whereas `1..5` gives you a range which does include `5`

eg:

```
>> (1..5).to_a
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4,
    [4] 5
]
>> (1...5).to_a
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4
]
```

Answer (score 1):

> The **three dots** indicates that the end stops before the terminator,
>   **two dots** indicates it includes the terminator.

SRC: http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.pt/2008/11/loops.html

`1...5` -> 1 to 4

`1..5` -> 1 to 5

Comment: In addition, there's a big difference between using two dots and three dots with Ruby's [flip-flop operator](https://blog.newrelic.com/2015/02/24/weird-ruby-part-3-fun-flip-flop-phenom/). :-)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between inclusive and no inclusive ranges.

i.e.:

```
(1..5).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(1...5).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For this reason, your loops will have a different number of cycles.